# UI blocks during a function call

Tags: android

Suppose that I have 10 text views in my layout. I want to change their background one by one with a small delay between each operation. Here's a sample code:

```
public void test(){
    for (int i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        myTextViews[i].setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        try {
           Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that during the time of running this function main thread blocks and backgrounds don't change. They change all together when the program finishes running the function. What should I do if I want the user to see each background is changed at the correct time and then next one...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Thread.sleep()`, the thread you are actually blocking is the UI thread, which is why you're seeing a hang-up. What you need to do is start up another Thread to handle the sleeps, or delays, that you want, and then utilize the `runOnUiThread` method

Try this:

```
public void test() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //anything related to the UI must be done
                //on the UI thread, not this thread we just created

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        myTextViews[i].setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But you forgot .start() and the end of Thread definition ;)

Comment: And Also Thread.Sleep must be inside try{}catch{}
Just to mention a second way I should say runOnUiThread should works fine but I used Handler.Post to post the runnable to the main looper and this works just cool.

Comment: Thanks for taking time :)